# How can I catch all routes with apache and html

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I write a js script in index.html that parse URL and redirect to a proper destination. e.g it parses `example.com/#/info` and shows a proper link.

I want that it handle any URL such `example.com/xyz`. but it shows 404 error.
when I add `.htaccess` like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/#

# Rewrite all those to insert /folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But it doesn't work. it throws a `too_many_redirects` error.

Comment: Hashes are not sent to the web server--Apache, including PHP.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done just with html! you SHOULD use php or another server-side code. you can rename your file to index.php and set those rewrite rules and ..